# The method isBefore from momentjs does not work

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to check if one of the date is before taking into account the minute;

```js
// 1610459035000 Tuesday, 12 January 2021 13:43:55
// 1642081435000 Thursday, 13 January 2022 13:43:55
const a = moment(1610459035000).isBefore(1642081435000, 'minute');
console.log(a) //get true but expect false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Making `console.log(a)` i expect to get `false` because the minutes are the same in both cases even if the years are difefrent. 
 Why i get `true` if minutes are the same?

Comment: It compares the time rounded to the specified component, not compare only that component. If you want to compare only that component, extract that component to do comparison.

Comment: @RickyMo, i am not shure if i understand. Could you show please on my example?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? 2021 is beofre 2022, for sure isBefore returns true. Why do you expect a false?

Comment: You are probably looking for `moment(1610459035000).minute() < moment(1642081435000).minute()` where [`minute()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/) returns a number 0-59.

Answer (score 2):

See [the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/).

The second argument limits **precision**.

This means that if your dates were `2001-01-01T00:00:10` and `2001-01-01T00:00:05` then normally the one that is five seconds after midnight would be before the one that is 10 seconds after midnight. If you specify `'minute'` precision then it would ignore the difference in seconds and treat them as the **same** time.

On the other hand, `2001-01-01T00:00:00` and `2002-01-01T00:00:00` are different years. If you have minute precision then the seconds are ignored but one is still clearly before the other.

Only the parts of the values that are smaller then the specified level are ignored, not the parts that are larger.

Comment: so how to get the correct answer in my case?

Comment: @Asking it is correct. What do you expect and why? Please describe what you actually want to do.

Comment: @RickyMo, then when moment compare it will check  and years, and dues the fact the the years are different i get true?